# How to use Python custom logging handler for multiprocessing program

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

I have a main logger for a program where I added a custom logging handler to handle all error level messages. I don't need to save these logs to a file but I tried to keep all the log messages in a list.

I realize that the list may not be thread safe when multiple processes (using multiprocessing) may emit error records to it so my list always seem to store random results. Is there any way I can lock the list.append to make sure there is only one process accessing it at a time?

Comment: The obvious thing is to use a `multiprocessing.Lock()`, and stick the append in a `with <that_lock>:` block.  Have you tried that?

Comment: yeah, it is fine now, i will close the question.